# How can i display galleryview, imageview and gridview in same activity

Tags: android, gridview, imageview, gallery

I have a gallery in my android application when I clicked on gallery item I want to display image and grid view. I done when i have only three images in gallery and in click it displayed correctly. But now I have seven images in gallery and each gallery item there are four images to display gallery.In this I m using array of drwawable images only.In this time I got an exception as Java.lang.OutOfMemory i use below code

```
             public ImageThemeAdapter(Context c, Integer[] mImageIds) {
 imagesId=mImageIds;
 bitmap=new Bitmap[imagesId.length];
 mContext = c;
 TypedArray ta=obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.Gallery1);
    imageBackground=ta.getResourceId(R.styleable.Gallery1_android_galleryItemBackground, 1);
    ta.recycle();
    for (int i = 0; i <imagesId.length; i++) {
       bitmap[i]=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(),imagesId[i]);
    }
}

public int getCount() {
    return bitmap.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return bitmap[position];  
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {   

    ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);

    i.setImageBitmap(bitmap[position]);
    i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(130, 120));
   // i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams((ScreenWidth*80)/100, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    i.setBackgroundResource(imageBackground);
    return i;   
}
```

and my screen shot[image]

Please provide any suggestions Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can also use horizontal scrollview instead of gallery